# Append values are not fetching

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

The `div` appended value is not getting in controller but the appended thing is visible on the view page correctly and i had gone through several ways but couldn't reach to the correct point.

Here is my view section please have a look

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   
   var maxAppends = 0;
   function add_field(id)
     {
      
    var update_new = $('<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px">\n\
                      <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Documentsss</label>\n\
                      <div class="col-sm-5">\n\
                      <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">\n\
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new" >Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists" >Change</span><input type="file" name="files[]" ></span> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span><a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none;">&times;</a></div></div>\n\<div class="col-sm-2">\n\<strong>\n\
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove</a></strong></div>');
                      

maxAppends++;


  $(".update_new_"+id).append(update_new);
 
  }
</script>
```

```html
<div class=" table-responsive div1" id="EmpprintReport">
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table2excel">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>                        
                        <th>Document Name</th>
                        <th>Documents</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Expiry Date</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                      <?php
                      if(!empty($details))
                      {
                        foreach ($details as $value) {
                          ?>
                          <tr>
                          <td nowrap><?= $value->service_name;?></td>
                          <td nowrap>
                          <?php if (!empty($value->documents)): ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <!--  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><?= ('Documents') ?>
                                    : </label> -->
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <?php
                                    $uploaded_file = json_decode($value->documents);

                                    if (!empty($uploaded_file)):
                                        foreach ($uploaded_file as $sl => $v_files):

                                            if (!empty($v_files)):
                                                ?>
                                                <p class="form-control-static">
                                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'uploads/documents/' . $v_files; ?>"
                                                       target="_blank"
                                                       style="text-decoration: underline;"><?= $sl + 1 . '. ' . ('view') . ' ' . ('other_document') ?></a>
                                                </p>
                                                <?php
                                            endif;
                                        endforeach;
                                    endif;
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                          </td>
                          <td nowrap><?= $value->service_number;?></td>
                          <td nowrap><?= $value->expiry_date;?></td>
                          
                          <td>
                          <textarea id="<?php echo $value->id;?>" hidden> <?php echo $value->documents;?></textarea>
                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_<?php echo $value->id;?>" id="Button3" id="Button3"  class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="margin-top:5px;">
           <i class="far fa-edit text-white" title="Edit"></i></a>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm_delete"  name="delete" id="title" c-d-id="<?php echo $value->id;?>" clientid="<?= $id; ?>"  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deletedocument" style="margin-top:5px;">
             <i class="fa fa-trash text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete"></i></a></td>



                          </tr>
                          <div class="modal fade edit" id="edit_<?php echo $value->id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="padding:20px !important;">
  
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">        
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Document</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php
        $result=$this->Admin_model->get_services_by_id($value->id);
        //var_dump($value->id);
        ?>
          <form method="post" class="form_<?php echo $value->id;?>" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/edit-client-registration-details/<?= $value->id; ?>/<?= $id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label>Service Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="service_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter service name" style="width: 100%" value="<?= $value->service_name; ?>" />  </div>
    
          <div class="control-group">
          <label>Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="service_no" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number" style="width: 100%" value="<?= $value->service_number; ?>" />
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
          <label>Expiry Date</label>
          <input type="text" name="date" id="date_<?= $value->id; ?>" class="form-control input-sm datepick" data-bind="datePicker: StartDate" value="<?= $value->expiry_date; ?>" />
          </div>

          <div id="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?>" class="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?> item-row">
                <div class="form-group mb0" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                    <label for="field-1"
                           class="col-sm-4 control-label">Other Document</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($value->documents)) {
                                $uploaded_file = json_decode($value->documents);
                            }
                            if (!empty($uploaded_file)):foreach ($uploaded_file as $v_files_image): ?>
                                <div class="">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="fileName[]"
                                           value="<?php echo $v_files_image ?>">
                                  
                                    <span class=" btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <span class="fileinput-filename"> <?php echo $v_files_image ?></span>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCFile" style="float: none;">×</a>
                                    </span>
                                    <strong>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="RCF"><i
                                                class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove</a></strong>
                                    <p></p>
                                </div>

                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                <!-- Here i want the appended result and the result is coming but the values selected here is not passing to the controller while submitting-->
                            
                        </div>
                        <div id="msg_pdf" style="color: #e11221"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <strong><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="update_more" onclick="add_field('<?php echo $value->id;?>');" u_id="<?php echo $value->id;?>" class="addCF item-row-click update_more"><i
                                    class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add More
                            </a></strong>
                    </div>
                </div>

                

            </div>

          

          
        </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/resources/ajax-loader.gif" id="ajaxIndicator" style="display: none; margin-right: 10px" />
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-weight: bold" value="Edit Details" />&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
                          <?php
                        }
                      }
                      ?>
                        
                    </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                          <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                          </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                </table>

                  </div>
```

Comment: Any clue anybody have

Comment: Your explanation is not sufficient to really understand what is the problem. Could you add comments in your posted code to show which of these elements is shown and which one isn't?

Comment: @SaschaM78 what i mean here is i want to add additional data to the existing data so that i had chooses `append` method and the thing is what am appending is viewing on the page but the value selected in that are not getting while the form is submitting

Comment: @SaschaM78 i had added additional comments in the posted code please have a look

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean with "is not getting in controller". You have links `<a id="update_more">` (duplicate IDs are never good) triggering `add_field(ID)` so when clicking one of the links a new DIV containing a form should be added to the element `$(".update_new_"+id)`. Is that happening? Open the Developer Tools of your browser and check the Console if you see any errors after clicking the link.

Comment: I checked my console it 's not showing any error.yes what you understood is happening whenever clicking on `add_field(ID)` a new div will be added to the element  `$(".update_new_"+id)`.Here "not getting to the controller" means am following mvc(codeigniter) structure  and the values selected to the newly added content does not have any value while submitting the form.

Comment: Do you mean that the files that have been selected in the new DIV are not submitted to the controller for saving?

Comment: @SaschaM78 yes that i meaned..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193476/discussion-between-sascham78-and-user-777).