# append values are not getting in form while submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append, codeigniter-3

```html
public function edit_client_registration_details($c_id,$id)
{
  $data['active_mn']="user_registration_details";
 


  $fileName = $this->input->post('fileName');
  //var_dump($fileName);
  $file = $this->input->post('files');
  //var_dump($file);
  
  if (!empty($fileName)) {
      foreach ($fileName as $key => $name) {
          //$old['fileName'] = $name;
          
          $result[] =  $name;
      }

      $documents = json_encode($result);
      
  }
  
  if (!empty($_FILES['files']['name']['0'])) {
      $old_path_info = $this->input->post('fileName');
      
      $mul_val = $this->do_upload('documents');
      var_dump($mul_val);
      $documents = json_encode($mul_val);
  } 
  
  

  if (!empty($result) && !empty($mul_val)) {
      $file = array_merge($result, $mul_val);
      $documents = json_encode($file);
  }

 
  $data=array(
        'service_name' =>$this->input->post('service_name'),
        'service_number' =>$this->input->post('service_no'),
        'expiry_date' =>$this->input->post('date'),
        'link' =>$this->input->post('link'),
        'documents'=>$documents,
      );
      
 $update=$this->Admin_model->update_service($c_id,$data); 
  if($update)
  {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Reg Details Updated Successfully');
    redirect('admin/add-client-registration-details/'.$id);
  }
  else
  {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Failed');
    redirect('admin/add-client-registration-details/'.$id);
  }    
}
```

Here is my code,in this the values that are appended are not getting in the form and the values are not passing to the database.I got the appended view correctly but the values selected in that `append` function are not getting.
Here is my script

```js
var maxAppend = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.update_more', function() {
  var u_id = $(this).attr("u_id");

  var add_new = $('<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px">\n\
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Document</label>\n\
        <div class="col-sm-5">\n\
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">\n\
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new" >Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists" >Change</span><input type="file" name="files[]" ></span> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span><a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none;">&times;</a></div></div>\n\<div class="col-sm-2">\n\<strong>\n\
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove</a></strong></div>');
  maxAppend++;
  var resil = $(this).closest("#update_new_" + u_id).append(add_new);
  console.log(resil);

});
```

```html
  <form method="post" class="form_<?php echo $value->id;?>" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/edit-client-registration-details/<?= $value->id; ?>/<?= $id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?>" class="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?> item-row">
  <div class="form-group mb0" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Other Document</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">



      </div>
      <div id="msg_pdf" style="color: #e11221"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <strong>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="update_more" onclick="add_field('<?php echo $value->id;?>');" u_id="<?php echo $value->id;?>" class="addCF item-row-click update_more">
          <i class="fa fa-plus">
          </i>
          &nbsp;Add More</a>
      </strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What form? There is no form element in what you have shown. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Nevermind, this seems to be a duplicate of your own previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129546/append-values-are-not-fetching anyway.

Comment: @04FS sorry.. now i had added the form

Comment: @04FS yes this seems to be..but i didn't got a solution for this

Comment: That doesn’t justify creating duplicates, especially if your “waiting time” on the previous one so far wasn’t really that long. You edited the existing one two hours ago, so give people some time to notice and react to that. Plus there’s someone commenting on there in the mean time already that your explanation of the problem so far isn’t sufficient. So address the feedback there instead of creating duplicates, please.

Comment: Could you show how you handle the posted data on the controller? have you tried dumping the posted data on the controller?

Comment: @HastaDhana i had added controller here

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($file);` ?

Comment: its null value.